# Optimizing a Tic-Tac-Toe AI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe, ai

I built a Tic-Tac-Toe game in Python. The board is made of ASCII characters and it is the user versus an AI. The user chooses a number (1-9) and if the corresponding spot is open then either an 'X' or an 'O' will be placed there. I wrote it in Python 2.7, then upgraded to Python 3.4, so I made it compatible with that. I'm not sure if it is still compatible with Python 2.7. I think that I was able to clean up most of the code, but I feel like my AI code is a bit messy. The whole game is [here](https://github.com/michaelpri10/Tic-Tac-Toe/tree/126bc2ccc00c39a17eb26e3aa2b5c0f41574c6ae) on Github.

AI_turn.py

```
import random

def AI_turn_easy(board, possible_nums, AI_XO):

    # generates a random, available space on the board and makes it an 'O'
    randChoice = random.choice(possible_nums)
    possible_nums.remove(randChoice)
    board.spaces[randChoice] = AI_XO

    return possible_nums


def AI_turn_hard(board, possible_nums, AI_XO):

    # All of the possible winning configurations
    possible_configs = [["1", "2", "3"],
                        ["1", "4", "7"],
                        ["1", "5", "9"],
                        ["2", "5", "8"],
                        ["3", "6", "9"],
                        ["3", "5", "7"],
                        ["4", "5", "6"],
                        ["7", "8", "9"]]

    # Shuffles the configurations so the computer doesn't run through the same order every time
    random.shuffle(possible_configs)

    # Check each configuration; if there is two of the three spaces equal each other, put an 'O' in the other space
    for config in possible_configs:
        if board.spaces[config[0]] == board.spaces[config[1]]:
            if board.spaces[config[2]] in possible_nums:
                possible_nums.remove(board.spaces[config[2]])
                board.spaces[config[2]] = AI_XO
                return possible_nums
        elif board.spaces[config[0]] == board.spaces[config[2]]:
            if board.spaces[config[1]] in possible_nums:
                possible_nums.remove(board.spaces[config[1]])
                board.spaces[config[1]] = AI_XO
                return possible_nums
        elif board.spaces[config[1]] == board.spaces[config[2]]:
            if board.spaces[config[0]] in possible_nums:
                possible_nums.remove(board.spaces[config[0]])
                board.spaces[config[0]] = AI_XO
                return possible_nums
        else:
            pass

    # If there aren't any matches of two in any of the rows, choose a random, available space
    return AI_turn_easy(board, possible_nums, AI_XO)


def AI_turn_impossible(board, possible_nums, AI_XO):
    # All of the possible winning configurations
    possible_configs = [["1", "2", "3"],
                        ["1", "4", "7"],
                        ["1", "5", "9"],
                        ["2", "5", "8"],
                        ["3", "6", "9"],
                        ["3", "5", "7"],
                        ["4", "5", "6"],
                        ["7", "8", "9"]]

    # Shuffles the configurations so the computer doesn't run through the same order every time
    random.shuffle(possible_configs)

    # Check each configuration; if there is two of the three spaces equal each other, put an 'O' in the other space
    for config in possible_configs:
        if board.spaces[config[0]] == board.spaces[config[1]]:
            if board.spaces[config[2]] in possible_nums:
                possible_nums.remove(board.spaces[config[2]])
                board.spaces[config[2]] = AI_XO
                return possible_nums
        elif board.spaces[config[0]] == board.spaces[config[2]]:
            if board.spaces[config[1]] in possible_nums:
                possible_nums.remove(board.spaces[config[1]])
                board.spaces[config[1]] = AI_XO
                return possible_nums
        elif board.spaces[config[1]] == board.spaces[config[2]]:
            if board.spaces[config[0]] in possible_nums:
                possible_nums.remove(board.spaces[config[0]])
                board.spaces[config[0]] = AI_XO
                return possible_nums
        else:
            pass

    # Take either the middle or a corner piece, which makes it impossible to win (I think)
    for space in random.shuffle(['5', '1', '7', '3', '9']):
        if space in possible_nums:
            possible_nums.remove(space)
            board.spaces[space] = AI_XO
            return possible_nums

    return AI_turn_easy(board, possible_nums, AI_XO)
```

This is the code that runs the game

game.py

```
from board_class import Board
from difficulty import difficulty
from chooseXO import chooseXO
from AI_turn import AI_turn_easy, AI_turn_hard, AI_turn_impossible
from user_turn import p1_turn
from check_win import check_win
from play_again import play_again
import time

def main():
    def tic_tac_toe():
        # print("\n" * n) - makes it appear as if it is a new screen

        print("\n" * 500)

        diff = difficulty()
        time.sleep(1.5)

        board = Board()
        turns_taken = 0
        possible_nums = [str(i) for i in range (1,10)]
        last_move, AI_XO, p1_XO = chooseXO()

        while turns_taken < 9:
            print("\n" * 200)
            board.print_board()

            if last_move == "p1":
                print("AI's turn")
                time.sleep(1.5)
                if diff == "E":
                    possible_nums = AI_turn_easy(board, possible_nums, AI_XO)
                elif diff == "H":
                    possible_nums = AI_turn_hard(board, possible_nums, AI_XO)
                elif diff == "I":
                    possible_nums = AI_turn_impossible(board, possible_nums, AI_XO)
                last_move = "AI"    

            elif last_move == "AI":
                possible_nums = p1_turn(board, possible_nums, p1_XO)
                last_move = "p1"

            win = check_win(board, turns_taken)
            if win == None:
                pass
            else:
                break

            turns_taken += 1

        print("\n" * 200)
        board.print_board()

        if win == AI_XO:
            print("AI wins. You lose :(")
        elif win == p1_XO:
            print("You win :) Congratulations!")
        elif win == "draw":
            print("It was a draw")

        time.sleep(2)

    tic_tac_toe()

    times_played = 1
    while times_played < 10:
        print("\n" * 200)
        if play_again():
            tic_tac_toe()
            times_played += 1
        else:
            break

    print("Goodbye")
    time.sleep(1.5)
    quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a massive block or repeated code, instead make a function and call it two times:

```
def avoid_losing_and_win_if_possible(board):
    random.shuffle(POSSIBLE_CONFIGS)

    # Check each configuration; if there is two of the three spaces equal each other, put an 'O' in the other space
    for config in possible_configs:
        if board.spaces[config[0]] == board.spaces[config[1]]:
            if board.spaces[config[2]] in possible_nums:
                possible_nums.remove(board.spaces[config[2]])
                board.spaces[config[2]] = AI_XO
                return possible_nums
        elif board.spaces[config[0]] == board.spaces[config[2]]:
            if board.spaces[config[1]] in possible_nums:
                possible_nums.remove(board.spaces[config[1]])
                board.spaces[config[1]] = AI_XO
                return possible_nums
        elif board.spaces[config[1]] == board.spaces[config[2]]:
            if board.spaces[config[0]] in possible_nums:
                possible_nums.remove(board.spaces[config[0]])
                board.spaces[config[0]] = AI_XO
                return possible_nums
        else:
            pass
    return None


def AI_turn_hard(board, possible_nums, AI_XO):
    move = avoid_losing_and_win_if_possible(board)
    return move if move is not None else AI_turn_easy(board, possible_nums, AI_XO)


def AI_turn_impossible(board, possible_nums, AI_XO):
    move = avoid_losing_and_win_if_possible(board)
    if move: return move

    for space in random.shuffle(['5', '1', '7', '3', '9']):
        if space in possible_nums:
            possible_nums.remove(space)
            board.spaces[space] = AI_XO
            return possible_nums

    return AI_turn_easy(board, possible_nums, AI_XO)
```

---

**Modularization**: `print("\n" * 500)` is repeated many times in your code, you should name a small function:

```
def clear_screen():
    print('\n' * 500)
```

---

**Keep indentation low**: move the `tic_tac_toe` definition outside of `main`

---

**Avoid magic numbers**: `9` should be a constant `NUMBER_OF_SQUARES`, remember to use `possible_nums = [str(i) for i in range (1,NUMBER_OF_SQUARES+1)]` also `1.5` should be `TIME_TO_WAIT`.

---

**Don't lag**: `time.sleep(1.5)` why are you wilfully lagging?

---

**Minor idiom**: `thing is None` is better than `thing == None`

---

**Shadow built-ins for better usability**: `board.print_board()` is weird, modify your class in order to be able to call `print(board)` by shadowing `__repr__`

---

**Again about modularity**: A function like the following would make the code clearer and simpler to read.

```
def generate_end_message(win):
    if win == AI_XO:
        return "AI wins. You lose :("
    elif win == p1_XO:
        return "You win :) Congratulations!"
    elif win == "draw":
        return "It was a draw"
```

---

**Use dictionaries**: A dictionary would be less verbose here:

```
        if diff == "E":
            possible_nums = AI_turn_easy(board, possible_nums, AI_XO)
        elif diff == "H":
            possible_nums = AI_turn_hard(board, possible_nums, AI_XO)
        elif diff == "I":
            possible_nums = AI_turn_impossible(board, possible_nums, AI_XO)
```